# Rails 5.2 How to auto upload image by Carrierwave after choose a image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I used Carrierwave to upload images to polymorphic table.

With the following codes , I can upload and display the images correctly.

But now I want to auto upload and display image after choose a image in `new.html.erb`. In other words , I want to run

`Attachment.create(:attachment => params[:attachment], :attachmentable =>@img) if params[:attachment]`

before img **`create`** action, just after I choose a image.

What should I do with the codes? Thank you so much for giving me guidances.

Part of my codes as follows:

**My `Gemfiles` :**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

**My `img.rb`:**

```
class Img < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachmentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**My models of `attachment.rb`:**

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :attachment, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :attachmentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**My controller of `imgs_controller`**

```
class ImgsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @imgs = Img.all
  end

  def show
    @img = Img.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @img = Img.new
  end

  def create
    @img = Img.new(img_params)
    if @img.save
      Attachment.create(:attachment => params[:attachment], :attachmentable =>@img) if params[:attachment]
      redirect_to @img
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @img = Img.find(params[:id])
    @img.destroy
    redirect_to @img
  end

  private

  def img_params
    params.require(:img).permit(:img_name)
  end
end
```

**My html of imgs**

```
# new.html.erb

<%= form_for(@img,:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :img_name %>
  <%= file_field_tag :attachment %>
  <%= f.submit "upload" %>
<% end %>



# show.html.erb

<% @img.attachments.each do |f| %>
  <%= image_tag f.attachment.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post you want that as soon as the user browses the image from location you want that image to be uploaded to cloud storage using carrierwave.

One way of doing this would be making an ajax call to the controller after the user has completed the browsing of image from his system and remotely uploading the image to cloud.

Unnecessary:

But what happens if user keeps on changing the image while browsing, will you uploading each image browsed irrespective of the fact that you would not be showing that image or will be needing it.

Workaround:

You can use jquery to the read the image browsed and then show the image to the user if needed and when the form is submitted then only you upload the image to cloud storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Rohan.  In fact , I want to auto upload images in `Redcarpet`  after I choose a image , just like StackOverflow Markdown to choose and auto upload images, then call back the images url in markdown. So , to realize this , I had to making an Ajax to call the controller? Is there a simple way to call this action `Attachment.create(:attachment => params[:attachment], :attachmentable =>@img) if params[:attachment]` after choose a image ? Thanks again , @Rohan~ Bless you！

Comment: Hi, @Rohan, Can I transform this action `Attachment.create(:attachment => params[:attachment], :attachmentable =>@img) if params[:attachment]` to a `form_for`? If it can be transformed, How could I write the `form_for`? just like: `<%= form_for :attachments do |m| %>
    <%= m.file_field :attachment %>
    <%= m.submit %>
  <% end %>`,

Comment: Is there a simple way to call this action ..-> The simplest way of calling the action before the form submit is by making remote(ajax) call to the controller.

Comment: Can I transform this action ---> Since in the form submit you will be making 
an html call to the action and on the remote call it will be script type request.
What you can do is handle both type of request using the respond_to block where you will be handling both type of requests.